# Separating image into RGB channels and reconstructing original by stacking?

Tags: css, image-processing, photoshop

Is it possible to separate a photo's RGB channels in a way that if you stack the separate images on top of each other (say in an HTML page with the images being a transparent "channel" stacked on top of each other), you can see the original image the way it was?

I tried grabbing a selection from each channel and making making it a separate layer in that channel's color, but it seems like I'm missing something, or the way channels work is more complicated than I think.

The reason I ask is because if I could get this to work, then I could manipulate the opacity of each color separately using CSS and get some neat effects (without using canvas).

Comment: I know there was a script to do this in Paint Shop Pro, but I don't remember where to find it. It probably relies on blend modes that aren't available in a browser.

Comment: I've considered trying to do something similar to this myself but have yet to actually try it. It theoretically could work.

Comment: @JamWaffles--I don't think it is the channels he is trying to "do" in CSS, just the manipulating of opacity on stacked layers (like 3 div's with `.png` background images that contain the red, green, and blue channels saved out of photo software). This is certainly "possible" in CSS, though whether it can actually recreate the image I am not sure of.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered my own uncertainty on this:

**This process *cannot* recreate the original image.**

(Which is what JamWaffles said in short in his comment.) Here's the explanation why:

1. You *can* take a photo and split out the RGB channels from software like Photoshop.
2. You *can* manipulate those gray scale channels in such a way to add have various alpha levels of Red, Green, and Blue and save that into a `.png`. So far, so good.
3. You *cannot* recombine them correctly by layering in css. Assume you have some area of the photo that is white. Note the following:

**Alpha Channel Combining (is additive)**

Red Layer (255, 0, 0) + Green Layer (0, 255, 0) + Blue Layer (0, 0, 255) = ***You see RGB(255, 255, 255)***, i.e. white.

**CSS Layer Combining (is not additive; it will cover lower layers)**

Red (top) Layer (255, 0, 0) + Green (middle) Layer (0, 255, 0) + Blue (bottom) Layer (0, 0, 255) = ***You see RGB(255, 0, 0)***, i.e. only the top layer, which is red, as it covers the green and blue layers at the point where it is 100% opaque.

So until such a time as css may offer an option to have layers "add" to one another rather than "cover" one another, then such an idea is not possible. Now that is not to say you could not achieve some rather interesting effects with layered `.png`images with monochromatic colors, and later manipulating opacity of the layers further through css, you just cannot ever *recreate* the image through the stacking of the channels in css.

Comment: You might be able to pull it off by using svg filters (specifically feBlend=additive) applied to html elements https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content. However, it would only work in Firefox.

Comment: Interesting idea. Since he wanted to avoid `canvas` I don't know if svg would be something Bart would want to incorporate into it or not. But it may indeed create a possibility to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

According to this specification: http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/compositing-1/#mix-blend-mode
CSS can support color blending, it just isn't implemented on most browsers. However many
browsers support the use of color blending in the '2d' canvas context. This blog post 
demonstrates the use of canvas for color blending animations and an very basic explanation of the idea. http://mackenziestarr.co.nf/blog/?p=7

Answer (score 0):

**First step** : deconstruct your image
This web site does it well : https://www.aatbio.com/tools/online-image-channel-splitter-rgb

**Second step** : stack your images
With `position: absolute`, flexbox, grid layout, anything

**Third step** : make the magic
Set the css property `mix-blend-mode: lighten;` on all your images
There you go !

Follows a basic exemple, and [here's some fun of what you can do with it](https://codepen.io/hen-sen/full/zYXdwza)
Works on the last version of Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

```css
.imgPart {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}
```

```html
<img id="red" class="imgPart" src="https://i.ibb.co/2ZmFLTM/red.png" />
<img id="green" class="imgPart" src="https://i.ibb.co/zR8LfgQ/green.png" />
<img id="blue" class="imgPart" src="https://i.ibb.co/LkPwM0k/blue.png" />
```